# Weird segmentation fault 11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

There are two files:

> Matrix.hpp:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    size_t rows = 0;
    size_t cols = 0;
    T* data = nullptr;
public:
    Matrix() = default;
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix(size_t n, size_t m);
    T& operator() (size_t i, size_t j);
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(size_t n, size_t m) : rows(n), cols(m) {
    try {
        data = new T[rows*cols];
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
    delete[] data;
}

template <typename T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
    if (i < rows && i >= 0 && j < cols && j >= 0) {
        return data[(i+1)*cols + (j+1)];
    } else {
        throw std::logic_error("matrix indices out of range");
    }
}
```

and

> Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.hpp"

int main() {
    size_t n, k;
    std::cin >> n >> k;
    Matrix<long double> m = {n, k};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.getNumRows(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m.getNumCols(); ++j) {
            std::cin >> m(i,j);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.getNumRows(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "\n";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m.getNumCols(); ++j) {
            std::cout << m(i, j) << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm entering something like:

> 1  2  3  4

I can get

> 3 4

as answer but sometimes **the same** input causes `Segmentation fault 11` moreover when I'm changing template argument from long double to int, error disappears. How can I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you `return data[i*cols + j];` in `Matrix<T>::operator()`?

Comment: Not a bad matrix class, by the way, but you should consider replacing the array with a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to get [Rule of Three/Five compliance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Currently if you try to copy, assign or move a Matrix you're in for some nasty debugging. And the [std::exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) in the constructor will cause the program to exit without freeing all of it's resources.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm using default arrays under the hood for studying C++ (particularly I'm trying to deal with memory and designing default constructors and destructors). Also I'll consider your advise about std::exit. Thank you!

Comment: Good enough, but in that case, I'll recommend explicitly defining at least the copy constructor and operator= to prevent multiple Matrix objects pointing at the same data array. Currently given Matrix m and Matrix n, `m=n` will overwrite `m.data` with `n.data`, leaking the memory allocated for `m.data` and resulting in either a double delete of `n.data` or an adventure in undefined territory if m or n is deleted while the other is still in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator function is accessing data outside its bounds.
Passing (0,0) to the function should return data[0]. Currently it returns data[2].
Change line

```
return data[(i+1)*cols+(j+1)];
```

to

```
return data[i*cols+j];
```